# Mount all Nginx virtual hosts at subpathes of the default host

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have a Nginx setup with several virtual hosts (defined by `server` blocks for every linux home directory).

To allow a preview for domains that currently do not have a DNS entry pointing to my host, I like to show the correspondent site at eg. `http://myhost.com/example.com/index.html`.

For this example, I do this by

```
location /example.com {
    root /home/example.com/public_html;
    rewrite ^/example.com(.*)$ $1 break;
    rewrite_log off;
}
```

However, I would like a general solution that reroutes all vhosts.

In addition, is there a HTTP header equivalent to the HTML `<base ...>` tag, that Nginx could set to enable the use of `/` prefixed pathes in the sites?

Comment: Using `proxy_pass` would be cooler of course, as things that FCGI would work then, not only static sites. That would be cool. I still need to know how to provide a that `proxy_pass` rule for all pathes at once..

Comment: using proxy pass and [sub filter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_sub_module.html) (e.g. to inject a `<base>` tag) aught to permit you to do what you ask - try something =) or at least look for and read examples using those directives.

Comment: I don't find any example similiar enough to get the right replacements for all rules. I guess the `proxy_pass` and the `rewrite` directive both need to include variable parts filled by using a regulary expression in the `location` statement? Is this possible?